# Can't use etcd in the cluster

Tags: coreos, etcd

I've read [this](https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cluster-architectures/) guide about cluster architectures, and I've built a development cluster with this config:

All machines are on the same subnet.

One machine acts like a master, and runs **etcd** only (IP address is 192.168.0.95).

```
#cloud-config

coreos:

etcd:
  discovery: #url
  addr: $private_ipv4:4001
  peer-addr: $private_ipv4:7001

units:
  name: etcd.service
  command: start
```

I then have three workers that run **fleet** with this config:

```
#cloud-config

coreos:
  fleet:
    etcd_servers: "http://192.168.0.95:4001"
  units:
    name: fleet.service
    command: start
```

I can control machines and units via **fleetctl**, but I haven't been able to use **etcdctl** properly.

Each worker uses local **etcd** when working with keys, therefore keys exist on the worker they've been created on only!

Isn't this supposed to happen, given the above config?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to point `etcdctl` at the etcd cluster just like you're doing with fleet, right?

`etcdctl --peers "http://192.168.0.95:4001" ls /`